# Photoshop: show layer edges by default

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to set option "Show layer edges" (View -> Show -> Layer Edges) to true by default?

Answer (score 0):

Not looking possible with just Photoshop. I used ScriptListener on CS6 and it doesn't see any activity when the Show > Layer Edges menu item is toggled. Assigning a shortcut key doesn't help either.

You might want to check AutoHotkey (assuming you're on Windows). It can emulate the menu selection if you can hook into the File > Open and File > New events.